# Userform populates wrong table in word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I have been using google for a while and finally decided to ask here for help.
Basically I have a word documents with a couple of tables that is being used by different people. Each table has a VBA button "add new row". Click on a button and a userform is filled out. Userform populates the table. Only problem left is there are multiple tables and userforms and they populate the wrong table.

How can I populate the right tables with userforms?
Googling helped me that bookmarks are needed. I set a bookmark called

[Table and Bookmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Jq0.png)

[Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwlIG.png)

[Notation/Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6KbG.png)

Code for clicking add in userforms:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonAdd_Click()
    Dim table2 As table
    Dim newRow As Row
    
    Set table2 = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set newRow = table2.Rows.Add
    
    newRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = TextBoxFunction.Text
    newRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = TextBoxName.Text
End Sub
```

First time using VBA, credits go to this person: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9cZ_XWzQZX0

Many many thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you need a userform at all? If you use a *repeating section content control* around the second row of a table, there will be a plus icon at the end which duplicates the initial row with all content controls. User then enters data into the text content controls (instead of userform)

Comment: As you are already using content controls, though you ought to edit the prompt texts, there is no need for vba at all. Just keep it simple and add a repeating section content control, like Ike said.

Comment: Many many thanks guys. Repeating section content control solved it super easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You choose the table by index. If you have any mask you can recognize the correct table, you can try to check all the tables and recognize the right one with loop

```
Dim tempT as Variant
Dim count as long
count=0
For Each tempT in  ActiveDocument.Tables
count=count+1
if ActiveDocument.Tables(count) 'here some condition to recognize the corrct table ' Then 
Set newRow = table2.Rows.Add

'etc your code

End If 
Next tempT
```